# How to get unspecified fields from a non-strict Mongoose Schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have created a Mongoose schema for a collection in my database named 'instruments'. I made it non-strict because records to be inserted there could have a certain unknown number of field-value pairs. The field names and values are also unknown. Now, it successfully saves documents no matter what new fields are included but I have an issue where when I try to retrieve these documents, and refer to the dynamic field-value pairs inside using JS dot notation, I get undefined. I could successfully get the value of fields I have specified in my schema, though and when I print the whole document returned, I see the field-value pairs I am looking for. Is this natural Mongoose behavior? If yes, what can I do to still have the ability to get the fields not in the schema? See below codes for reference...

Schema for Instrument

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var subConfigsSchema = new Schema({
        alias: String,
        value: String,
        position: Number
    }, {_id: false});

    var configsSchema = new Schema({
        bfq: [subConfigsSchema],
        qpa: [subConfigsSchema],
        fmb: [subConfigsSchema],
        cz: [subConfigsSchema]
    }, {_id: false});

    var instrumentSchema = new Schema({
        _id: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            auto: true
        },
        configs: {
            type: configsSchema,
            required: true
        }
    },
    {
        strict: false,
        versionKey: false
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Instrument', instrumentSchema)
```

Sample query

```
    Instrument.find({_id: '5c9b3747407939296c5af1da'}, function(err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;

                instrument = data[0];

                console.log(instrument);
                console.log(instrument._id);
                console.log(instrument.inpname);
                console.log(Instrument['inpname']);
    });
```

Output right now is:

```
    { _id: 5c9b3747407939296c5af1da,
      inpname: 'Nome',
      configs:
       { bfq: [ [Object] ],
         qpa: [ [Object] ],
         fmb: [ [Object] ],
         cz: [ [Object] ] } }
    5c9b3747407939296c5af1da
    undefined
    undefined
```

I expect both undefined's to be 'Nome'.